# How to find in VSPackage which version control system a solution uses

Tags: c#, version-control, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I'm new to extending Visual Studio and I'm trying to find way to find which source control system is used by current solution.

I created VsPackage project and I am able to obtain reference to solution via `IVsSolution` and to hook up to solution events via `IVsSolutionEvents`.

Inside `OnAfterSolutionOpen` (or possibly some other if there's an alternative) I would like to act differently basing on whether the solution uses TFS or Git or something else. How can I obtain this information?

I plan to support as many Visual Studio versions as possible, but if it isn't possible I would like to support at least VS2012 and higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after several hours of digging I've found a solution to this. Thanks to the [article](http://blog.markrendle.net/2014/03/27/disable-the-git-source-control-add-in-in-vs2013-permanently/) of Mark Rendle and the source code for his [NoGit extension](https://github.com/markrendle/nogit) I've found, that the list of registered source control plugins is located in registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\SourceControlProviders` (in case of VS 2013).

So now, we can have both plugin guid, and the name of the provider. This sample code can fetch those values:

```
var key = @"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\" + "12.0" + @"_Config\SourceControlProviders";

var subkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key);
var providerNames = subkey.GetSubKeyNames().Dump();
var dict = new Dictionary<Guid, String>();
foreach (var provGuidString in subkey.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    var provName = (string)subkey.OpenSubKey(provGuidString).GetValue("");
    dict.Add(Guid.Parse(provGuidString), provName);
}
```

Now, there are two ways I've found to obtain guid of currently active provider.

**important update**: Apparently the second way of obtaining currently active plugin does not work as expected. I strongly advise using first solution.

1. This is the way that bases on the extension mentioned earlier:

   ```
   var getProvider = GetService(typeof(IVsRegisterScciProvider)) as IVsGetScciProviderInterface;
   Guid pGuid;
   getProvider.GetSourceControlProviderID(out pGuid);
   ```
2. Or we can just go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\CurrentSourceControlProvider` and get the default value of this key:

   ```
   var key2 = @"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\CurrentSourceControlProvider";
   var guidString = (string)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key2).GetValue("");
   var currentGuid = Guid.Parse(guidString);
   ```

Now we just take `var activeProviderName = dict[currentGuid];` and that's all.

Comment: No one did provide any more insights, so I am marking this as an answer.